# PR2 stacks (and actions) under Diamondback

Tags: ros-diamondback, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to get ahead of my colleagues and port my OpenPRS/PR2 library under Diamondback, but it looks like the PR2 stacks and actions have not yet been released under Diamondback. Can somebody confirm?

I did the Desktop-Full Install: (Recommended)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full
```

and include such as  `pr2_common_action_msgs/TuckArmsAction.h` are nowhere to be found.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9441/pr2-stacks-(and-actions)-under-diamondback/) by [felix](https://answers.ros.org/users/154/felix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please follow the PR2-specific instructions for installing Diamondback:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/PR2/diamondback

Installation page for specific robots are linked off the ROS installation page:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation

(5 robots and counting).

If you're really curious as to what a particular variant contains, you should look at [REP 108](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html) for the common entry point descriptions.   If you're really, really curious, you can look at the rosinstall file for that variant:

http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1